# JQuery autocomplete dropdown not showing at expected place

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have implemented a panel where user can post their thoughts with images. For every post there is a reply box similar to the facebook timeline. User can mention any user while replying to any post and I tried to make this mentioning easier. I have used a JQuery UI(JS and CSS) autocomplete dropdown to suggest the username when **@** sign and **some other letters** are typed(similar to FB or Skype ).As expected, the reply box are dynamically generated. I have made a single autocomplete dropdown and attached it with a reply box which get focused. For this I used this function to set the **position** -

```js
$("#hidden-autocomplete").autocomplete("option", "position", { of: "#" + currentReplyBoxId } );
```

Everything is working fine except the dropdown position. The dropdown appears over the input field so user can't see what he has typed so far. See the image -

[image]

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/arshoma_shohag/y6nhxuaq/14/) I've made a reproducible example.

But I want this like below -

[image]

Now dropdown is below the input field , the height is fixed and scrollable. Am I doing something wrong? Could you please help me to get the desired results? TIA

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello @Twisty , please see this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/arshoma_shohag/y6nhxuaq/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to set all 3 jQuery UI position properties:

```
my: "left top",
at: "left bottom",
of: "#" + currentId
```

Here is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yg5sdxw6/2/

Comment: Yes, it's working now. Thank you @Vladislav. One more thing to add in css to make the list scrollable, max-height and overflow-y.

Comment: Please be aware that one does not "need" to specify all three. jQuery UI assignes `"center"` for the `my` and `at` values. In this case, making use of them will allow the element to appear in the desired location.